# Mapbox : Image is black if its size is greater than 2048 * 2048

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I try to add an image on a map with Mapbox.
I followed this link : https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/image-source/

If size of image is greater than 2048*2048, image appears in black like this:
[image]

Image should normally appear like this:
[image]

How to make the image not appear in black without limit?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running into this known issue with the iOS Maps SDK: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/12989.

One possible workaround is to upload the Geo-referenced image to your Mapbox account, then add it to your map as an `MGLRasterStyleLayer` at runtime. You can see an example of this approach here: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/image-source/

#### Edit: more detail regarding the suggested workaround

Mapbox's iOS Maps SDK allows you to apply raster tiles at runtime. You can also [upload geo-referenced images (a.k.a. GeoTiffs) to your Mapbox account](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/georeferencing-imagery/) and Mapbox will convert this to a raster tileset and provide you with a "Map ID" that allows you to retrieve this tileset from Mapbox's API. A Map ID looks like this: `riastrad.1ckjd53j` (i.e. "username.unique_id").

Once you have a Map ID you can use this to add the raster tileset to any map at runtime with one of the GL SDKs.

On iOS, the boilerplate code for this looks like the following:

```swift
import Mapbox

class RasterSourceExample: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: MGLStyle.darkStyleURL)
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.457, longitude: -75.789), zoomLevel: 4, animated: false)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        mapView.tintColor = .darkGray

        // Set the map view‘s delegate property.
        mapView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) { 
        // Create the raster tile source object
        let source = MGLRasterTileSource(identifier: "tileset-source", configurationURL: URL(string: "mapbox://riastrad.1ckjd53j"))

        style.addSource(source)

        // Create a raster layer from the MGLRasterTileSource.
        let rasterLayer = MGLRasterStyleLayer(identifier: "raster-layer", source: source)

        style.addLayer(rasterLayer)
    }
}
```

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/image-source/ is not the good link to make MGLRasterStyleLayer ?

Comment: If you want to know how to georeference your image and upload it to your Mapbox account you can follow this tutorial: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/georeferencing-imagery/

Comment: How to use MGLRasterStyleLayer ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've updated my response to include more detail on the suggested workaround.

Comment: @riastrad can you please guide me for similar issue on Mapbox SDK version 10.x.x ?as MGLRasterStyleLayer is deprecated or removed in version 10.x.x.

Comment: @mrunalthanki I'm no longer working at Mapbox and not as up to date on the SDKs as I once was. I'd recommend reaching out to their support team: https://support.mapbox.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000291231